# Suddenly getting Can't resolve error from runtime-corejs3 on webpack build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, polyfills

I have been using this setup for a while. I sometimes had similar error but I was able to fix by removing ^ on versions. However, this time it does not seem to work. I cannot build the project anymore.

List of errors. It shows similar error for all of them. And weird thing is it suddenly happen when I did not update anything and try to rebuild.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/core-js-pure/modules/es.array.splice.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../internals/array-species-create' in '/var/www/xx.ca/app/node_modules/core-js-pure/modules'

ERROR in ./node_modules/core-js-pure/modules/es.array.flat.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../internals/array-species-create' in '/var/www/xxx.ca/app/node_modules/core-js-pure/modules'

ERROR in ./node_modules/core-js-pure/internals/get-iterator.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../internals/an-object' in '/var/www/xxx.ca/app/node_modules/core-js-pure/internals'
```

I was adding core-js/stable and regenerator-runtime in entry point file

```
import 'core-js/stable'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
```

my babel.js is like this.

```
   {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "useBuiltIns": "usage",
      "corejs": 3,
      "targets": {
        "ie": "11"
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    [
      "babel-plugin-webpack-alias",
      {
        "config": "${PWD}/config/aliases/aliases.config.js"
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/transform-runtime", {
      "corejs": 3
    }],
    "react-imported-component/babel",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions"
  ]
}
```

This is some of the version I am using right now

```
"@babel/core": "7.6.2",
"@babel/register": "7.6.2",
"@babel/runtime-corejs3": "7.6.2",
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/core": "7.6.2",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.6.2",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.2.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-spread": "^7.6.2",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
"core-js": "3.2.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this issue by removing some part and adding new plugin.

I removed

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
```

from the entry point

and added

```
 "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
```

I still do not know how it broke since nothing was changed.